# When loading a C++ dll in C#, does the CLR load the dependencies of the C++ file automatically?

Tags: c#, c++

Well that is my question, I am planning to implement a C++ dll which has many C++ dependencies, and I want to use it in my c# code..What I wanted to know is if the CLR loads the dependencies on its own or will I have to do something else.
When loading a C++ dll in C#, does the CLR load the dependencies of the C++ file automatically?

Comment: What compiler are you using to compile your C++ code.  In addition if the C++ is actually C++/CLR the answer to this question is entirely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a native C++ dll, the dependencies are loaded at load time, unless that dependency is marked as delay loaded, which it will then get loaded when one of the functions from that dll is called.

If its a .Net C++ dll, dependencies are loaded when needed.

Comment: Third alternative is if the DLL itself is dynamically loading other DLLs via `LoadLibrary()`, which is sometimes done for internationalisation using resource-only satellite DLLs (this is an old technique though).

Comment: @RogerRowland: While that's technically possible, such resources are generally not considered "dependencies".

Comment: @MSalters - yes, I agree, I was just pointing out a situation where a deployed application may fail to work due, for example, to missing language modules and that it may be difficult to identify this "dependency" before run time.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the answer is no. The *CLR* does not load the dependencies of a native DLL -- but that's purely a technicality -- they will be loaded automatically (if possible and available).

What actually happens is slightly complex. The CLR doesn't (itself) load DLLs at all -- DLLs are loaded by the native Windows loader. In the case of a .NET assembly, you have the CLR code stored as basically a binary resource. You also have a DllMain that invokes the native entry point to the CLR. When the CLR is invoked from DllMain, it initializes the assembly.

The normal Windows loader will also (of course) load native DLLs. In this case, the loader (in the absence of a delayload flag) will go through the DLLs dependencies and load them as well. Even if the loading of the initial DLL was triggered from the CLR, the CLR will have no further involvement until the DLL and all its implicit dependencies have been loaded. Only *after* all those DLLs (could also include things like fonts, executables, etc.) are "loaded" will control return to the CLR at all.

Note I put "loaded" in quotes there for a reason -- the DLL won't normally be loaded into memory either -- the loader will just set up page tables to map it to memory, and then those pages will be loaded on demand (though some pages, such as those holding *that* DLL's DllMain will be loaded more or less immediately, when its DllMain is invoked).

So assuming you have a .NET assembly that uses a native DLL with native dependencies, the sequence would be:

1. Load assembly
2. assembly's DllMain invokes CLR
3. CLR loads native DLL
4. Loader loads all dependencies of the native DLL
5. Only after all the implicit dependencies are loaded, control returns to CLR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if they are available in the search paths (i.e. application path, windows system path etc.)